# Codeigniter and .htaccess mod rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am having an issue with mod rewrite. I am also a total beginner to it. I am using CodeIgniter and trying to rewrite the following:

http://url.dev/news/news_selection?item=59

to look like this:

http://url.dev/news/news_selection/59/

I have followed a tutorial on: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/ (more specifically the : "Patterns and Replacements" section)

The issue is I write my RewriteRule as below and it still does not rewrite the url after going to the page (eg. http://url.dev/news/news_selection?item=59)

```
RewriteRule    ^news/news_selection/([0-9]+)/?$    news_selection?item=$1    [NC,L]
```

*Any advice on where I am going wrong? Thank you.*

I am not sure if the routes and controller affect this issue but I added them for reference below.

In my routes for codeIgniter I have

```
//_News Folder
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'pages/view2/_news/$1';
```

- **1: _news is the folder**
- **2: news_selection is the php file**
- **3: pages is the controller**

My controller has the following function for view2:

```
public function view2($sub ='', $page='')
  {
          if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$sub.'/'.$page.'.php'))
          {
                  // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                  show_404();
          }

          $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter

          $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
          $this->load->view('pages/'.$sub.'/'.$page.'.php', $data);
          $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
  }
```

The rest of my .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after about 10 hours of trying everything today.

I decided that it may be a routing issue with CI and decided to try passing my variable from the url in the cleaned up format. So...

If I enter: http://url.dev/news/news_selection/59

It will work with the following route:

```
//_News Folder
$route['news/news_selection/(:num)'] = 'pages/view_test/_news/news_selection/$1';
```

and controller:

```
  public function view_test($sub='', $page='', $var1='')
  {
          if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'/views/pages/'.$sub.'/'.$page.'.php'))
          {
                  // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
                  show_404();
          }

          $data['item'] = $var1;

          $this->load->view('templates/header');
          $this->load->view('pages/'.$sub.'/'.$page.'.php', $data);
          $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
```

By using these I can pass the page number as `$var1` and then pass it on to my view via `$data`. Then I picked up `$data['item']` as `$item` in my news_selection.php page and passed it to my model for processing. [Reference to CI Manual for this.](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view)

After that the page processes like it normally would have.

Answer (score 1):

You just need this to use url as above:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

You can use this for all controller. This file .htaccess is in application folder.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more in depth? The website works fine with: http://url.dev/news/news_selection?item=59 as a url. I just want to clean it up where you enter: http://url.dev/news/news_selection/59/ and it rewrites it for passing.

Comment: I don't know much about this. But I read an article about CodeIgniter URL, if you set `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;` it will display an url like a query string. Because the first time I use CI, my url is normal,not like a string.
You can read more at: [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/urls.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help. This isn't the answer for me as it will break form helper along with a few other things. I think this is a different way to go about accessing your model and views via variables. I finally did figure out how I had to do it and have posted my answer below.